# testing pixijs examples in jsfiddle or anywhere else?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, pixi.js, codepen

I'm just getting started learning Pixijs, and I'd like to test some of the examples.

When I copy this example:
https://pixijs.io/examples/#/filters-basic/displacement-map-flag.js

into JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ripmurdock/42h7fckx/4/

I get a black box and this error in the console:
Invalid X-Frame-Options header was found when loading “https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true”: “ALLOWALL” is not a valid directive.

I'm more familiar with codepen.  Codepen support said running this example was Pro feature.

What's a good way to test the Pixijs examples in JSfiddle or anywhere else?

```
const app = new PIXI.Application();
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

app.stage.interactive = true;

const container = new PIXI.Container();
app.stage.addChild(container);

const flag = PIXI.Sprite.from('examples/assets/pixi-filters/flag.png');
container.addChild(flag);
flag.x = 100;
flag.y = 100;

const displacementSprite = PIXI.Sprite.from('examples/assets/pixi-filters/displacement_map_repeat.jpg');
// Make sure the sprite is wrapping.
displacementSprite.texture.baseTexture.wrapMode = PIXI.WRAP_MODES.REPEAT;
const displacementFilter = new PIXI.filters.DisplacementFilter(displacementSprite);
displacementFilter.padding = 10;

displacementSprite.position = flag.position;

app.stage.addChild(displacementSprite);

flag.filters = [displacementFilter];

displacementFilter.scale.x = 30;
displacementFilter.scale.y = 60;

app.ticker.add(() => {
    // Offset the sprite position to make vFilterCoord update to larger value. Repeat wrapping makes sure there's still pixels on the coordinates.
    displacementSprite.x++;
    // Reset x to 0 when it's over width to keep values from going to very huge numbers.
    if (displacementSprite.x > displacementSprite.width) { displacementSprite.x = 0; }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use pixi.js in a code snippet platform, you first need to load the library in the way that the tool offers.

In JSFiddle, you'll find an input field when you expand the **Resources** section of the sidebar.

In Codepen, you can load arbitrary external scripts from the settings menu. You'll find a text field under **Settings -> JS -> Add External Scripts/Pens** where any external JavaScript file can be imported.

These fields usually offer auto completion for popular libraries delivered by various CDNs. After typing `pixi.js`, it automatically gets imported as `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/7.1.3/pixi.min.js`.

Additionally, you need to update the URLs of the assets imported in the examples. Change the relative URLs (hosted in the same directory as the example) to absolute URLs. Instead of `examples/assets/pixi-filters/flag.png`, you need to provide the complete route to the external resource `https://pixijs.io/examples/examples/assets/pixi-filters/flag.png`. This applies to all other assets that the example might load, including the displacement map.

[This](https://codepen.io/epaezrubio/pen/zYJogPj) is a working Codepen with all these fixes in place. And [this](https://jsfiddle.net/epaezrubio/oc3yh0x9) is the same example running on JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  Is there an asset hosting site that doesn't generate errors on either jsfiddle or codepen?  I uploaded a couple of test images to w3spaces.com.  Both jsfiddle and codepen display images in the results window, but the pixeljs div is blank and both jsfiddle or codepen have similar errors in the console:  Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://fcd1.w3spaces.com/basketclip.png.

Comment: It looks like both jsfiddle and codepen allow github assets to be used with pixijs, and they will display assets from w3spaces.com, but they block any pixijs transformations from being applied to assets hosted on w3spaces.com.  Any idea where I can upload assets for testing pixijs?  Here the images hosted on  w3spaces.com are displayed, but pixijs is blocked from using those images:  https://jsfiddle.net/ripmurdock/examL49p/6/  https://codepen.io/fcdobbs/pen/RwYKWrj